# SQL getting only one max id field on a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to compare the value of the user table with only one maximum value of the notifications of the table?

```
SELECT "vkId" AS "id"
FROM "user" AS "user" 

LEFT OUTER JOIN "notification" ON "notification"."userId" = "user"."vkId"

WHERE (
"user"."vipEnd" < 1469714507 
AND "user"."vipEnd" > 1469710907
) AND (
(
    "notification"."type" = 4
    AND 

    "notification"."expiresVipDate" < 1469710907
) 
OR "notification"."id" IS NULL
)


LIMIT '100';
```

Comment: Tip of today: Use table aliases!

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here.  What determines what a `maximum` value is?

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior! (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.) And you can remove that "notification"."id" IS NULL...)

Comment: "notification"."expiresVipDate"

Comment: Perhaps you need to join not the "notification" table but only the most recent record in it for each user. Is that right?

Comment: It just isn't clear what result you want here.

Can you explain the business case, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use DISTINCT ON for that, sorting by expiresVipDate DESC:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u."vkId") u."vkId" AS id, n.*
FROM "user" AS u
LEFT JOIN notification n ON (n."userId" = u."vkId" AND
                             n.type = 4 AND
                             n."expiresVipDate" < 1469710907)
WHERE u."vipEnd" < 1469714507 AND u."vipEnd" > 1469710907
ORDER BY u."vkId", n."expiresVipDate" DESC
LIMIT 100;
```